# Mysql -u root not working, can't change password, reinstalling doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

So, all of a sudden, for no reason I could find, mysql simply stopped working in my computer. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and I've tried to reinstall mysql about 4 times, all to no avail. Whenever I try to do anything, it gives me `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, and trying [this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) gets me as far as step 2:
Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command -
 `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
, which seems to work until I try the next step and get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`
 I searched this error online, and they told me to change some config files to include `--skip-grant-tables`, which I did and it didn't work, either.

What else can I do? I've been trying to fix this for around three hours to no avail, and I can tell you with 100% certainty that when I left work yesterday it was working just fine. Please, is there anything I can do short of wiping the entire damn disk and starting everything over?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](//superuser.com).

Comment: Well, mysql is a tool used primarily for programming, isn' it?

Comment: Asked it there anyway, thanks!

Comment: MySQL is a database that stores information. You can program applications to get said data, however, that doesn't mean MySQL is primarily used for `programming`. If you had a programming question for something like c#, php, python, etc., which connects to MySQL then sure, this site would be helpful, otherwise your question is for the other site

Comment: Makes sense. I asked it over there, thanks!